How to share functions between C++ classes when the member object they operate on is defined differently (stack vs heap)?
I have a situation where I have one class, A, which contains the same functions as class B,
but A defines it's own object on the stack to perform functions on, whereas B obtains it's object externally.
The name of the object and syntax is the same for each function in both classes.
A (made up) example:
class A
{
private:
   int numbers[200];

public:
   A() {};

   int do_stuff()
   {
      return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
   }
};


class B
{
private:
   int *numbers;

public:
   A(int *num): numbers(num) {};

   int do_stuff()
   {
      return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
   }
};

Despite it being trivial example, you can see how it will get wasteful if there are 20 functions and each is a copy-paste of the other.
Please don't waste collective energy arguing as to why A is better than B or vice-versa, I'm aware what I'm trying to achieve and it's non-trivial, unlike the above.

A(int *num): numbers(num) {}; doesn't compile. This code and A() {}; have excessive semicolons.

I'm not convinced that both classes need to exist. If there is no compelling reason, choose neither and make numbers a std::vector.

A::numbers is wherever the instance of A it is a member of happens to be. Whether it is in the free store ("on the heap") or automatic ("on the stack") is up to the user.

what  molbdnilo says. The actual important difference between A and B is whether they own the array or not

Learn about std::array vs. std::vector. Your class B is just an accident waiting to happen since it has no model of "ownership" whatsoever. Then also learn about the rule of 0/3/5 and then think again about class B and how it might be problematic.

If the difference between A and B is indeed non-trivial, as alleged, then that non-triviality is bound to affect the solution to the code duplication. So this question is by its own admission incomplete. We don't need the exact precise reason, but we need to have a fundamental understanding of the problem domain.

Evidently, the OP is talking about the copy-paste of 20 or more of the same functions into different classes, which is a simple problem that can be resolved by a common same base class.

You can achieve this with a template.
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class X {
 public:
  X() requires(!std::is_pointer_v<T>) = default;
  explicit X(T n) requires std::is_pointer_v<T>
      : numbers(n) {}

  int do_stuff() { return numbers[0] + numbers[1]; }

 private:
  T numbers;
};

using A = X<int[200]>;
using B = X<int*>;

int main() {
  int ar[2]{};
  A a;
  B b(ar);
}


This template solution is over-kill, especially, it is merely a little difference between <int[200]> and <int*>, which are essentially the same. You can use pointers to pass them exactly in the same way.

The templates were originally introduced for avoiding repetitive implementations that is what I'm doing with the template example.

but, based on what op described, A and B contain many other different things.

but A defines it's own object ... whereas B obtains it's object externally. The name of the object and syntax is the same. Where do you see A and B contain many other different things?

that's just my impression from op's non-trivial real things, but the provided example is trivial as op stated. anyway, op may need clarify 'non-trivial'.

This is a great answer. Probably will select it as it's the only answer which doesn't create additional runtime overhead. Expanded Question: could this template approach be easily modified such that depending on which variants is defined, an additional number "F" is either supplied as a template argument or as a member variable + constructor argument? Might be pushing the bounds of what's possible with templates.

Your question rephrased: "I have two use cases. Once I need to do X another time i need to do X and Y. How can I avoid to implement X twice?"
Why would you implement X twice? Use what you have already.
class B
{
private:
   int *numbers;
public:
   B(int *num): numbers(num) {}
   int do_stuff() { return numbers[0] + numbers[1]; }
};

class A {
private:
   int numbers[200];
public:
   B b{&numbers[0]};
};

You asked to put considerations about design aside, hence I only show the most simple which comes at the cost of requiring a user to write a.b.do_stuff when they use an A.

sizeof A is not the same as in the question.

@3CxEZiVlQ so? It's private data either way

@Caleth I suppose they refer to the (public) B b member which adds to the size. Not sure if that matters. Anyhow its difficult to talk about design when OP asks to not worry about design

You could reasonable make B a private base class of A, so you can say using B::do_stuff;. This gives you a function-by-function decision whether you want to reuse the implementation or use an optimized function instead.

This solution is so called containment pattern. In reality, if A and B are equally complex and do many other totally different things except for a few functions doing the same things, this containment pattern should be avoided.


How to share functions between C++ classes when the member object they operate on is defined differently (stack vs heap)?

The Class A and B in your currently trivial example will be inefficient if there are more than two  same functions.
What you can try to define a base class that contains the common function, an abstract function to provide access to the data (stack vs heap).
class Base {
protected:
    virtual int* getNumbers() = 0;

public:
    int do_stuff() {
        int* numbers = getNumbers();
        return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    }
};

Then Class A and B can inherit from this base class and implement the accessor.
class A : public Base {
private:
    int numbers[200];  // stack

protected:
    int* getNumbers() override {
        return numbers;
    }
};

class B : public Base {
private:
    int* numbers;  // heap

public:
    B(int* num) : numbers(num) {}

protected:
    int* getNumbers() override {
        return numbers;
    }
};

Live Demo

This solution is not scaleable if there are many functions involved, because you'll mess up with many different gets, and end up with don't know which is which.

@James1  I think there are still a few ways we can keep improve ... using templates, smart pointers ... Would you mind expressing provide more details, to justify your scaleable?

You introduced in more functions (gets) for all functions in base class. It is more confusing to maintain one-to-one correspondence. It is not cleanly maintainable.

You have in fact two distinct problems: you want to be able to handle some processing on structured data (here a mere integer array), and you want to be able to use either an externally provided data, or to be able to own the data memory. As those are 2 distinct concerns they should be handled by two distinct classes.
Here is a possible code based on your example:
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


class B
{
private:
    int* numbers;

// allow late initialization from subclasses
protected:
    B() {};
    void set_numbers(int* num) {
        numbers = num;
    }

public:
    B(int* num) : numbers(num) {};

    // processing is only declared/defined in B
    int do_stuff()
    {
        return numbers[0] + numbers[1];
    }
};


// class A will let superclass B handle the data processing
class A: public B
{
private:
    // the std::array automatically handles copy/move/destruction
    std::array<int, 200> numbers;

public:
    A() :
        numbers{ 2, 3 } { // default initialization of numbers data...
        // use a 2 time construction because B is constructed before numbers
        B::set_numbers(numbers.data());
    };
};

int main() {
    int numbers[200] = { 12, 13 };
    B b(numbers);
    A a;
    std::cout << "a.do_stuff(): " << a.do_stuff() << " - b.do_stuff: " << b.do_stuff();
    return 0;
}

This correctly gives:
a.do_stuff(): 5 - b.do_stuff: 25

